# Environ variables in .env file in Django and docker

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm using Docker to build a Django web application for production via Docker-Compose and it uses the .env.prod file for the environmental variables. The docker-compose file works fine and deploys to a server with no issues via CI/CD on GitLab.

I was hoping to use the same kind of structure but just have a .env.dev file so I don't have to modify the settings file in any way. The problem I'm having is I can't find how to set environment variables from an external file in development mode. Right now running the command "python manage.py runserver" doesn't pick up the .env file with the data. The only workaround I can see is having a local_settings.py file which I was hoping to avoid. Example of what I'm trying to achieve below in the settings.py file.

```
DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))
```

with a .env.dev file.

```
DEBUG=1
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 149.28.188.180 [::1]
```

Thanks in advance. I'm sure I'm missing something easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a command "copy" in your local Dockerfile, that copy your local .env file for use inside docker container.
As example:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --update \
nodejs \
nodejs-npm && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY package.json /package.json
RUN npm i --silent --prod
#COPY .env /.env
COPY app.js /app.js
COPY bin/ /bin
COPY lib/ /lib
COPY server/ /server
COPY sql/ /sql
EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

As you can see is just uncomment the line with "copy"command, to copy your local environment.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, the docker container works fine with the .env files however when I run python manage.py runserver it doesn't seem to be able to use the enviroment variables.

Comment: do you use lib python-dotenv in your project?

Comment: I do now! Thanks mate, appreciate it. The docker-compose still works with the .env.prod file but locally using a .env file next to settings.py I can manipulate variables for local development. Huge help since I can turn debug on for local development but stipulate it off when the application heads to the docker-compose file.